# How to find Eigenvalues of Sturm-Liouville problem? Getting wrong Imaginary Eigenvalues

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I want to find Eigenvalues of following Sturm-Liouville problem

```
D[(2 - MA/κ[s]) q'[s], s] + W Ω^2 q[s] == 0,
```

Where `Ω^2` is the eigenvalue I want to find.

To do so I use the following code

```
 KS[L0_, λ0_, l0_, χ0_, s0_, step0_, stepnumb0_] := 
 Module[{L = L0, l = l0, λ = λ0, χ = χ0, j, 
           s = s0, step = step0, stepnumb = stepnumb0}, 
           X2 = Table[{0, 0}, {stepnumb}];
            For[j = 1, j <= stepnumb, j++,   
            Λ = Sqrt[(Cosh[L/(2 l)] - λ^2 + 
            ( λ^2 - 1) Cosh[s L/l])/(λ^2 ( Cosh[L/(2 l)] - 1))]; 
             X2[[j, 2]] = κ /. 
             FindRoot[χ (Λ^4) /κ^2 - χ + 
             2 Log[κ] + 2 L/(Pi 60000000) Cos[Pi s] == 0, {κ,
             1}]; X2[[j, 1]] = s; s = s + step;];
         Return[X2];]
 step1 = 1/10000;
 stepnumb = (1/2 + 1/2)/step1 + 1;


  SOL45 = Table[{0, 0}, {101}] ;
For [i = 1, i <= 101, i++,
 λ = 1.5;
 j = (i - 1)*0.524 + 1; X3 = Table[{0, 0}, {stepnumb}] ; 
  X3 = KS[1*60000000*Pi, λ, 1*60000000*Pi/6, j/1000, -1/2, 
    step1, stepnumb];
f = Interpolation[X3, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 20];
 ζ  = 3;
  Ct = 5/100; 
 χ = j/1000; 
 MA = N[(2 ζ  χ )  /(ζ + 1) * Ct ]; 
ρe = Exp[-L/(Pi H) Cos[Pi s]]; 
W = (Pi^2 Λ^4 )/(ζ + 1) (2 κ[s]^2 ζ - (MA - 2) ρe )/(2 κ[s] - MA); 
  L = N[1*60000000*Pi];
 l   = N[1*60000000*Pi/6]; 
 H = 60000000;   
Λ = 
Sqrt[(Cosh[
   L/(2 l)] - λ^2 + ( λ^2 - 1) Cosh[
     s L/l])/(λ^2 ( Cosh[L/(2 l)] - 1))]; κ[s] = 
f[s];
SOL45[[i, 1]] = j;
SOL45[[i, 2]] = 
NDEigenvalues[ {-D[(2 - MA/κ[s]) q'[s], s] /W, 
DirichletCondition[q[s] == 0, s == -1/2], 
DirichletCondition[ q[s] == 0, s == 1/2]}, q, {s, -1/2, 1/2}, 2];
]
      SOLPLOT45 = Table[{0, 0}, {100}];
      For[i = 1, i <= 100, i++,
       SOLPLOT45[[i, 1]] = SOL45[[i + 1, 1]]/1000;
 SOLPLOT45[[i, 2]] = Sqrt[SOL45[[i + 1, 2, 1]]];
  ]
 F45 = Interpolation[SOLPLOT45, InterpolationOrder -> 10]
P45 = Plot[F45[χ], {χ, 0, 0.0524}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Dotted}, AspectRatio -> 2/3]
```

As a result I get the following set, whcih contains complex numbers and Plot wich doesn't make any sense, as I know that all Eigenvalues are real and positive in this case

[image]
However the code works fine for other case, which just seems a bit different from expected Eigenvalue

```
 SOL1 = Table[{0, 0}, {101}] ;
For [i = 1, i <= 101, i++,
 λ = 1;
 j = (i - 1)*3 + 1; X3 = Table[{0, 0}, {stepnumb}] ; 
X3 = KS[1/4*60000000*Pi, λ, 1/4*60000000*Pi/6, j/1000, -1/2, 
 step1, stepnumb];
  f = Interpolation[X3, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 20];
 ζ  = 3; Ct = 2/100; χ = j/1000; 
 MA = N[(2 ζ  χ )  /(ζ + 1) * Ct ]; ρe = 
 Exp[-L/(Pi H) Cos[Pi s]]; 
 W = (Pi^2 Λ^4 )/(ζ + 
    1) (2 κ[s]^2 ζ - (MA - 2) ρe )/(2 κ[
      s] - MA); L = N[1/4*60000000*Pi];
 l = N[1/4*60000000*Pi/6]; 
 H = 60000000;   Λ = 
 Sqrt[(Cosh[
     L/(2 l)] - λ^2 + ( λ^2 - 1) Cosh[
      s L/l])/(λ^2 ( Cosh[L/(2 l)] - 1))]; κ[s] = 
 f[s];
  SOL1[[i, 1]] = j;
 SOL1[[i, 2]] = 
 NDEigenvalues[ {-D[(2 - MA/κ[s]) q'[s], s] /W, 
  DirichletCondition[q[s] == 0, True]}, q, {s, -1/2, 1/2}, 2];
 ]
 SOLPLOT1 = Table[{0, 0}, {100}];
For[i = 1, i <= 100, i++,
SOLPLOT1[[i, 1]] = SOL1[[i + 1, 1]]/1000;
SOLPLOT1[[i, 2]] = Sqrt[SOL1[[i + 1, 2, 1]]];
]
 F1 = Interpolation[SOLPLOT1, InterpolationOrder -> 10]
 P1 = Plot[F1[χ], {χ, 0, 0.301}, PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
  AspectRatio -> 2/3]
```

[image]

**Simplified code**

For example if I take the following values

```
     KS[L0_, λ0_, l0_, χ0_, s0_, step0_, stepnumb0_] := 
     Module[{L = L0, l = l0, λ = λ0, χ = χ0, j, 
         s = s0, step = step0, stepnumb = stepnumb0}, 
        X2 = Table[{0, 0}, {stepnumb}];
        For[j = 1, j <= stepnumb, j++,   
        Λ = 
       Sqrt[(Cosh[
         L/(2 l)] - λ^2 + ( λ^2 - 1) Cosh[
          s L/l])/(λ^2 ( Cosh[L/(2 l)] - 1))]; 
         X2[[j, 2]] = κ /. 
         FindRoot[χ (Λ^4) /κ^2 - χ + 
         2 Log[κ] + 2 L/(Pi 60000000) Cos[Pi s] == 0, {κ,
         1}]; X2[[j, 1]] = s; s = s + step;];
        Return[X2];]

   step1 = 1/10000;
  stepnumb = (1/2 + 1/2)/step1 + 1

 λ = 1;
 j = (79 - 1)*0.524 + 1; X3 = Table[{0, 0}, {stepnumb}] ; X3 = 
KS[1*60000000*Pi, λ, 1*60000000*Pi/6, j/1000, -1/2, step1, 
stepnumb];
f = Interpolation[X3, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 20];
ζ  = 3; Ct = 2/100; χ = j/1000; MA = 
N[(2 ζ  χ )  /(ζ + 1) * Ct ]; ρe = 
Exp[-L/(Pi H) Cos[
  Pi s]]; W = (Pi^2 Λ^4 )/(ζ + 
    1) (2 κ[s]^2 ζ - (MA - 2) ρe )/(2 κ[
      s] - MA); L = N[1*60000000*Pi];
  l = N[1*60000000*Pi/6]; H = 60000000;   Λ = 
  Sqrt[(Cosh[
    L/(2 l)] - λ^2 + ( λ^2 - 1) Cosh[
     s L/l])/(λ^2 ( Cosh[L/(2 l)] - 1))]; κ[s] = f[s];

SOL100 = NDEigenvalues[ {-D[(2 - MA/κ[s]) q'[s], s] /W, 
 DirichletCondition[q[s] == 0, s == -1/2], 
  DirichletCondition[ q[s] == 0, s == 1/2]}, q, {s, -1/2, 1/2}, 2];
SOL100
```

Gives the answer  ***{4.28055 - 15.1245 I, 4.28055 + 15.1245 I}***

Where I know that the answer for the first Eigenvalue should be around **1.58**

May I ask you for any ideas how to improve code to find Eigenvalues I do seek.

Comment: Readers typically avoid such long and slow-running  blocks of code.  Please consider simplifying your problem, probably by providing code to derive a single eigenvalue and comparing it with your expected value.

Comment: Followed your advice and added simplified case.

Comment: I ran your simplified code using Version `10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)` and obtained `{5.83485, 7.91617}` as the answer.  This is not the answer you predicted, but it is real.  Please copy your simplified code into a new notebook, run it in a new session, and see what you get.

Comment: I recommend that you precede your code with `Clear[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]]` to prevent old values of constants from corrupting the output of `KS`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the "Simplified Code" provided in the OP's last edit, `Λ` in the definition of `KS` is identically `1`, and the argument of `FindRoot` in the definition of `KS` is

```
frarg = χ (Λ^4) /κ^2 - χ + 2 Log[κ] + 2 L/(Pi 60000000) Cos[Pi s]
(* -0.041872 + 0.041872/κ^2 + 2. Cos[π s] + 2 Log[κ] *)
```

Zeros of `frarg` are shown in

```
ContourPlot[frarg == 0, {s, -1/2, 1/2}, {κ, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

and which solution`FindRoot` chooses depends on the initial guess provided.  For instance, an initial guess of `0.3` leads to the upper curve in the plot above, and corresponding eigenvalues `{3.46382, 12.5554}`, while an initial guess of `0.1` leads to the lower curve in the plot above, and corresponding eigenvalues `{2.11177, 6.51226}`.  The latter is closer to the result predicted by the OP.  On the other hand, the initial guess `1` used in the question leads to a mixture of solutions from the two branches.  Consequently, the resulting eigenvalues are meaningless in that case.

For completeness, note that `Solve` also can be used to find `κ`.  Since the two curves in the plot above do not cross, one need only choose the `First` or `Last` root from `Solve` to obtain the desired curve.

It seems likely that the erratic behavior in the first plot in the question occurs because of problems with `κ`.

**Addendum: Replace `KS`, etc. by `FunctionInterpolation`**

The "Simplified Code" section of the question can itself be simplified significantly by using `FunctionInterpolation` to replace `KS`, `Interpolation` and associated variables.

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]]
j = (79 - 1)*524/1000 + 1; χ = j/1000;
L = 60000000*Pi; l = 60000000*Pi/6; H = 60000000;  
λ = 1; ζ  = 3; Ct = 2/100; MA = (2 ζ χ)/(ζ + 1)*Ct; 
Λ = Sqrt[(Cosh[L/(2 l)] - λ^2 + (λ^2 - 1) Cosh[s L/l])/(λ^2 (Cosh[L/(2 l)] - 1))];
f = FunctionInterpolation[First[κ /. Quiet@NSolve[χ Λ^4/κ^2 - χ + 2 Log[κ] + 
    2 L/(Pi 60000000) Cos[Pi s] == 0, κ]], {s, -1/2, 1/2}, InterpolationPoints -> 101];
ρe = Exp[-L/(Pi H) Cos[Pi s]]; 
W = (Pi^2 Λ^4 )/(ζ + 1) (2 f[s]^2 ζ - (MA - 2) ρe )/(2 f[s] - MA); 
SOL100 = NDEigenvalues[ {-D[(2 - MA/f[s]) q'[s], s]/W , 
    DirichletCondition[q[s] == 0, s == -1/2], DirichletCondition[q[s] == 0, s == 1/2]}, 
    q, {s, -1/2, 1/2}, 2]
(* {2.11177, 6.51225} *)
```

(Use `Last` instead of `First` to choose the upper instead of the lower curve in the plot above.)  Because `f[s]` is a slowly varying function, the number of evaluations of `κ` can be reduced from `10001` to `101`, and `InterpolationOrder` reduced to its default value of `3`.

**Second Addendum: Curves for the original question**

Looping over the code just above is straightforward and give the curves desired in the first part of the question.  (Note that values of `λ` and `Ct` differ from those in the code just above so as to agree with the values in the first part of the question.

```
L = 60000000*Pi; l = 60000000*Pi/6; H = 60000000;  λ = 1.5; ζ  = 3; Ct = 5/100;
Λ = Sqrt[(Cosh[L/(2 l)] - λ^2 + (λ^2 - 1) Cosh[s L/l])/(λ^2 (Cosh[L/(2 l)] - 1))];
ρe = Exp[-L/(Pi H) Cos[Pi s]]; 
sol = Table[χ = j/1000; MA = (2 ζ χ) /(ζ + 1) * Ct; 
    f = FunctionInterpolation[First[κ /. 
    Quiet@NSolve[χ (Λ^4) /κ^2 - χ + 2 Log[κ] + 2 L/(Pi 60000000) Cos[Pi s] == 0, κ]], 
    {s, -1/2, 1/2}, InterpolationPoints -> 101];
    W = (Pi^2 Λ^4)/(ζ + 1) (2 f[s]^2 ζ - (MA - 2) ρe )/(2 f[s] - MA); 
    {χ, Sqrt @@ NDEigenvalues[{-D[(2 - MA/f[s]) q'[s], s]/W, 
    DirichletCondition[q[s] == 0, s == -1/2], DirichletCondition[q[s] == 0, s == 1/2]}, 
    q, {s, -1/2, 1/2}, 1]},
    {j, 1, 524/10, 524/1000}];
ListLinePlot[sol]
```

[image]

As noted in the first addendum, just replace `First` by `Last` to obtain results for the upper branch of `κ` in the first plot.  Doing so yields

[image]

Finally, using `L = 60000000*Pi/4; l = 60000000*Pi/24` along with `λ = 1; Ct = 2/100` and a broader range of computation, `{j, 1, 7492/25, 524/100}`, reproduces the final plot in the question, validating the approach used in this answer.  (Note that, for j much larger than `7492/25`, no real values for `κ` exist near `s == 0` for the parameters chosen, and `FunctionInterpolation` issues a plethora of error messages.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment I will try this method.

Answer (score 6):

I'll start with the equation the OP uses in the `FindRoot[]` call.  It can be simplified and solved exactly symbolically.  The following `eq1`, `eq2`, and `eq3` are equivalent under the indicated transformations:

```
Clear[a, b, s, κ, L, χ, Λ];

cvt = {a -> 2 L/(Pi 60000000) Cos[Pi s] - χ,  (* convert to OP's "Simplified coode" *)
       b -> χ (Λ^4)};
eq1 = χ (Λ^4)/κ^2 - χ + 2 Log[κ] + 2 L/(Pi 60000000) Cos[Pi s] == 0;  (* original *)
eq2 = b/κ^2 + 2 Log[κ] + a == 0;                                      (* basic form *)
eq3 = b/κ2 + Log[κ2] + a == 0;                                        (* κ2 == κ^2 *)

Simplify[eq1] ===
 Simplify[eq2 /. cvt] ===
 Simplify[eq3 /. κ2 -> κ^2 /. cvt, κ > 0]
(*  True  *)
```

All of the `Solve[]` commands below give the warning:

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

The equation `eq2`, like the OP's `eq1`, has two solutions, but clearly both cannot be correct, since they have opposite signs and the equation is not symmetric with respect to `κ`:

```
Solve[b/κ^2 + 2 Log[κ] + a == 0, κ]
(*
  {{κ -> -((I Sqrt[b])/Sqrt[ProductLog[-b E^a]])},
   {κ -> (I Sqrt[b])/Sqrt[ProductLog[-b E^a]]}}
*)
```

If we replace `κ^2` by `κ2` (`eq3`), we get just one solution.

```
Solve[b/κ2 + Log[κ2] + a == 0, κ2]    
(*  {{κ2 -> -(b/ProductLog[-b E^a])}}  *)
```

This is the solution we'll start with.  The warning by `Solve[]` suggests trying other branches of `ProductLog[]`, that is, `ProductLog[r, -b E^a]` for various integers `r`.  To verify the solutions for the OP's equation, we will need to plug in the actual numerical parameters for the system.  This will be done below.  It turns out there are two branches that solve the equation, `r == 0` and `r == -1`.  We use this code to construct the function `κ[s, r]` in the solution further down.

```
ksol = κ -> Sqrt[κ2] /. Solve[b/κ2 + Log[κ2] + a == 0, κ2] /. cvt
(*
  {κ -> Sqrt[-((Λ^4 χ)/ProductLog[-E^(-χ + (L Cos[π s])/(30000000 π)) Λ^4 χ])]}
*)
```

Here is the adapted code. I've made some changes to make the interdependencies a bit easier to manage.

```
(* initialize numeric parameters *)
step1 = 1/10000;
stepnumb = (1/2 + 1/2)/step1 + 1;

λ = 1;
j = (79 - 1)*0.524 + 1;
ζ = 3;
Ct = 2/100;
χ = j/1000;
MA = N[(2 ζ χ)/(ζ + 1)*Ct];
L = 1*60000000*Pi;
l = 1*60000000*Pi/6;
H = 60000000;

(* initialize functions *)
ClearAll[X2, X3, SOL100, κ, W, Λ, ρe];
KS[L_, λ_, l_, χ_, s0_, step0_, stepnumb_, root_] := 
  Module[{κ, Λ},
   Table[
    With[{s = s0 + (j - 1) step0},
     Λ = Sqrt[(Cosh[L/(2 l)] - λ^2 + (λ^2 - 1) Cosh[s L/l])/(λ^2 (Cosh[L/(2 l)] - 1))];
     {s,  
      κ /. FindRoot[χ (Λ^4)/κ^2 - χ + 2 Log[κ] + 2 L/(Pi 60000000) Cos[Pi s] == 0, 
        Evaluate@If[root == 0, {κ, 1, 0.35}, {κ, 0.1, 0.2}]]}
     ],
    {j, stepnumb}]
   ];

mem : X2[root_] := 
  mem = KS[1*60000000*Pi, λ, 1*60000000*Pi/6, j/1000, -1/2, step1, stepnumb, root];

ρe[s_] := Exp[-L/(Pi H) Cos[Pi s]];
W[s_, r_] := (Pi^2 Λ[s]^4)/(ζ + 1) (2 κ[s, r]^2 ζ - (MA - 2) ρe[s])/(2 κ[s, r] - MA);
Λ[s_] := Sqrt[(Cosh[L/(2 l)] - λ^2 + (λ^2 - 1) Cosh[s L/l])/(λ^2 (Cosh[L/(2 l)] - 1))];
κ[s_, r_] := 
  Sqrt[-((Λ[s]^4 χ)/ProductLog[r, -E^(-χ + (L Cos[π s])/(30000000 π)) Λ[s]^4 χ])];

mem : SOL100[root_] := 
  mem = NDEigenvalues[{-D[(2 - MA/κ[s, root]) q'[s], s]/W[s, root],
     DirichletCondition[q[s] == 0, s == -1/2],
     DirichletCondition[q[s] == 0, s == 1/2]},
    q, {s, -1/2, 1/2}, 2];
```

The two solutions, `root = 0` and `root = -1`:

```
Block[{root = 0},
 Print["eigenvalues"[root] -> SOL100[root]];
 Show[
  Plot[κ[s, root], {s, -1/2, 1/2}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.015]},
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
  ListPlot[X2[root], PlotStyle -> Red]
  ]
 ]

(*  "eigenvalues"[0] -> {3.46382,12.5554}  *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Block[{root = -1},
 Print["eigenvalues"[root] -> SOL100[root]];
 Show[
  Plot[κ[s, root], {s, -1/2, 1/2}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.015]},
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
  ListPlot[X2[root], PlotStyle -> Red]
  ]
 ]

(*  "eigenvalues"[-1] -> {2.11177,6.51226}  *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It turns out to be difficult to test the correctness of the solutions symbolically, so I settled for checking numerically.  For values of `r` in `ProductLog[r, z]` other than `0` or `-1`, we get nonzero imaginary residuals that grow with `Abs[r]`.  That indicated to me that there were no other solutions.  Below we give code for checking the two valid cases. (Note `ProductLog[0, z] === ProductLog[z]`.)

```
SetPrecision[
 eq1 /. Equal -> Subtract /. ksol /. Λ -> Λ[s],
 $MachinePrecision] /. 
   s -> RandomReal[{-1/2, 1/2}, 1000, WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision] // Abs // Max

(*  0.*10^-15  *)

SetPrecision[
 eq1 /. Equal -> Subtract /. ksol /. {ProductLog[z_] :> ProductLog[-1, z]} /. Λ -> Λ[s],
 $MachinePrecision] /. 
   s -> RandomReal[{-1/2, 1/2}, 1000, WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision] // Abs // Max

(*  0.*10^-14  *)
```

Comment: It should be noted that only two branches of the Lambert function have real values; $W_0(x)=W(x)$ is real for $x\ge-\frac1e$, and $W_{-1}(x)$ is real for is real for $-\frac1e\le x<0$.